# How to add another city in Windows 8's Weather

Tags: windows-8, weather

How can another city be added on Windows 8's Weather, so simply like on the iPhone?

(The reason why we need that is, sometimes we live in a city and need to commute to a different city to work, or we may wonder how the temperature is like for friends and family who live in another city, or to check the weather of a ski resort 4 hours driving away to decide when or whether to go or not, or if there is a trip we are planning to go to in a month, say, Paris, and we'd like to add the weather there easily before going.)

Answer (score 2):

On a notebook, a method is to right click inside of Weather, and choose "Places" to add any city.  To switch to view info of different cities we added earlier, again, right click and choose "Places".

Comment: +1 for sharing the answer (although I already knew, but for others :)